# 'new' operator in Javascript for Error() handling

Tags: javascript, error-handling, es6-promise

I am working with Promises and found that when rejecting is recommended to pass an `Error()` object as argument in order to enable error handling.

I find some examples where a `new Error()` is given and some others where only  `Error()` is passed.

After testing several cases I just do not find any difference between one usage and other, as seen here where both rejects seem to behave exactly the same:

```
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(reject, 1000, Error("Nope...")); 
    //setTimeout(reject, 1000, new Error("Nope..."));       
});    


p.then(val => { console.log(val) })
.catch(error  => { console.error(error.message) });
```

In this case, which practical difference is between both error handling ways?

Comment: I should have know this was a duplicate question. If you'll un-accept, I'll delete my answer. (Duplicate questions aren't necessarily a bad thing. In this case, I don't think my answer adds much of anything that isn't covered by the dupetarget's answers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After testing several cases I just do not find any difference between one usage and other...

That's because when you call `Error` as a function (without `new`), it acts exactly like you'd called it with `new`. That is, `Error(x)` and `new Error(x)` do exactly the same thing. This is a "feature" of the `Error` function. Normally, there's a difference between calling a function without new and calling it with `new`, just not in this case.

From [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-error-constructor):

> The Error constructor:
>
> - ...
> - ...
> - creates and initializes a new `Error` object when called as a function rather than as a constructor. Thus the function call `Error(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Error(…)` with the same arguments.
> - ...